# Bending Energy of regular planar curves is parameterization invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, curves, plane-curves

I need to show that the Bending Energy of a Planar Curve

$$\int_I {\kappa^{2}||\gamma^{'}||}$$

is invariant under a reparameterization of $\gamma$

I'm not really sure how exactly I go about doing this. If I can say choose a parameterization for $\gamma(t)$ like $<\cos t, \sin t>$ then calculate the bending energy then just reparameterize like, say, $<\cos(-t), \sin(-t)>$ or like $<\cos(t^{2}), \sin(t^{2})>$ and then recalculate and show these two bending energies are the same?

Or would I need to prove it in a more general sense (as opposed to specific examples) and if so, how exactly would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out on this. Looking forward to a lively and interesting discussion!

Comment: It is enough to show that the bending energy (that is something like $\int\frac{v}{R^2}$) is also the bending energy associated with the arc-length parametrization (for which $\|\dot\gamma\|=1$). Do you know Frenet's formulas?

Comment: So what you're saying is to parameterize by arc length the curve $\gamma(t)$ then take the bending energy of that and show it's of the form $\int{\frac vR^{2}}$? 

And do you mean the frenet-serret formulae?

Comment: Please ignore the $\frac{v}{R^2}$ part, that is related with a physical interpretation. I am just saying: consider the change of variable that brings $\gamma$ into its arc-length parametrization and check that the bending energy is invariant.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying Jack. What I have a problem with is how would I represent this in the abstract? Or could I just pick a parameterization (like the one described above), check its length to make sure its not already arc-length parameterized and then parameterize by arc length that curve and then perform both calculations of the bending energy and show they are equivalent?

Comment: Also how do the Frenet-Serret Formulae play into this?

Comment: Exactly. The Frenet-Serret formulas play a major role since you may describe a curve through them or just in the usual parametric way; the conversion between these reference "systems" and the computation of a Jacobian give that the bending energy is the same in the general parametric framework and in the arc-length parametrization, hence it is the same in every parametric framework.

Comment: So is what you're saying a suggestions on how to do this in a general, abstract sense? As in I convert from the parametric form to the so-called TNB-Frame and then do change of variable with a jacobian to show it's bending energy is invariant? I'm not quite sure I follow. Or could I literally just parameterize the curve then reparameterize it by arc length and perform the calculations?

Comment: The calculations involve a change of variable, i.e. a jacobian: you are just saying twice the same thing :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

I thought the total context should be comprehensively clear. So I shall attempt to reply more about how it comes about so directly in classical mechanical energy considerations. (I was never a teacher).

Stretching and Bending are the two fundamental phenomena of elastic motions.They are subjects of first two Mechanics chapters in a Strength of Materials course for linear elements. In classical mathematical surface theory we have as surface extensions  manifolds dealing with first and second fundamental forms.

In Stretching for a "line manifold", the linear spring we have energy conservation

$$ P_s + K_s = \frac12 k x \cdot x + \frac12 m {\dot x}^2 $$

which when differentiated with respect to time $t$  yields harmonic motion along $x$ as

$$ { m \ddot x} + k \,x=0 $$

Next in Bending energy of elstic curves like the Elastica, the bending potential energy  and bending kinetic energy sums

$$  P_b + K_b = \frac12 k_b\theta \, \theta + \frac12 I {\dot \theta }^2 $$

which by differentiation with time

$$ k_b \theta + I \, \ddot \theta =0 $$

depicting  harmonic rotary motion. Now your question is about  potential energy. We have Moment or Torque $ M= k_b \, \theta $

$$ dP_b = \frac12\ M d \theta = \frac12\, M \frac{d \theta}{ds} ds =\frac12\ M \,\kappa \,ds \tag1 $$

by virtue of *Euler Bernoulli theorem*  Moment Curvature relation with flexural rigidity $EI$ determines bending geometry

$$ \frac{M}{EI}=\kappa \tag2$$

Plug in

$$ dP_b = \frac{M^2}{2EI} ds \tag3$$

So the total physical strain energy of bending is

$$  P_b = \int \frac{M^2}{2EI} ds = \frac{EI}{2} \int \kappa^2 ds\tag4$$

And this *maximum potential* *bending energy* is conserved in any arc based parametrization of the curve under dynamic motion when kinetic energy is zero in extreme positions.. i.e., when $ \omega= \dot \theta =0$.

It can be noted that it is the total energy $ P_b + K_b$ that is conserved but never $ P_b $ alone at all instants of time due to energy conservation principle.

*Whatever be the parametrization you bend it and the curve stores static flexural energy.*

EDIT2:

*Isometric invariance relations of curves built on first fundamental form differential coefficients*

Freedom from parametrization for quantities depending on quantities dependent on first fundamental form. They can be as a class described as [***Natural Equations***](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalEquation.html)
E.g.,

$ \frac{d\phi}{ds}=\kappa = f(s)$ is intrinsic equation for *any curve* in the plane for all f,  the Cesàro equation.

$ \frac{d\phi}{ds}=\kappa =1 $ is intrinsic equation for a Circle.

$ \phi = $ constant is intrinsic equation for a straight line.

$ \frac{d\phi}{ds}=\kappa = a\cdot s $ is intrinsic equation for Cornu's spiral.

$ \frac{d\phi}{ds}=\kappa = 1/R, \, R^2 = 2 a s ,\quad, R^2+ s^2 =1. $ for well known curves.

The parametrization can be done *upto Euclidean motions* translation and rotation that is coordinate free.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this relates to what I'm asking. It looks like you're showing me how to derive the bending energy functional from some differential but 'M' isn't defined, nor is theta it seems or the parameter s so I'm not really sure what to make of it. In the end you say "and this bending energy is conserved in any arc based reparameterization" so are you saying that only that type of bending energy will be parameterization invariant under arc length param.?

Comment: OK. depicting above with context which I thought  is needed for the question.

Comment: Okay I see, I really appreciate your analysis and derivation as it is quite interesting but I think you're approaching it from a very specific context where it wouldn't make sense if I started writing using those arguments in my Diff Geo course. I must admit I don't quite see why the resulting Pb integral is parameterization invariant. I know you said it but I don't quite see it.

Comment: But again, I appreciate the effort you've put in to try to explain this to me

Comment: Can we say the straight line and circle are parametrization independent?