# Kinetic Energy Functional for Curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, compactness, calculus-of-variations, curves

Consider the kinetic energy functional:

$$ E(\alpha) = \frac 12\int_I ||\alpha^{'}(t)||^{2}dt$$

for the curve $\alpha$

(i) Show $E$ is not Parameterization invariant

(ii) Show that $\alpha$ is a critical point of $E$ under compactly supported variations $\alpha_s$ iff $\alpha^{''} = 0$. i.e., $\alpha(t) = x_0 + tv$ is a constant speed straight line (notice no assumptions on the regularity of the curve is needed.)

(iii) What are the minima of $E$?

For..

(i) I just am unsure as to whether to perform this in a specific case (i.e., explicitly state the parameterization and reparameterization I'm doing (say just $t$ then $-t$)) or in the general case (i.e., use properties about the energy functional in order to prove it in the abstract) and if in the general case how exactly I should start that.

(ii) I know I'm supposed to use the calculus of variations here but I'm really unfamiliar with it especially the terms "compactly supported variations $\alpha_s$" I am unfamiliar with the term but I imagine the s denotes particular "variations" on the curve but if someone could help with me whats being varied and how to represent that mathematically I would really appreciate it.

(iii) On this I just imagine you find $E^{'}(t) = 0$ then perform whatever test you like to verify its a minima?

Comment: Is this different from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176555/bending-energy-of-regular-planar-curves-is-parameterization-invariant ? Is this homework?

Comment: It's pretty clearly a different problem (albeit similar in optics) and yes it is homework. I'm not asking for solutions, I'm asking for help. Being that I don't know anyone in my class and my professor isn't the most amiable I figured this would be the quickest and most efficacious way to work my way through these problems.

Comment: You have no square on the norm ?

Comment: Oh I apologize, just an oversight in typing up the equation. I'll fix that now. Thanks for the catch @JeanMarie!